# one of the following statements is true.Identify:-

Tags: real-analysis

one of the following statements is true.Identify:-

(A) Every subset of $\Bbb{Q}$ which is bounded above has a unique supremum rational number.
(B)Every subset of $\Bbb{Q}$ which is bounded above has a unique supremum real number.
(C)The set of rational numbers has least least upper bound property.
(D)The set of real numbers does not have the greatest lower bound property.

---

I am confused because I think both B and D are correct but they say only one option is correct

Answer (score 2):

They are all wrong.

(A) $\{x\in \mathbb Q\mid x^2<2\}$ is bounded from above (e.g. $42$ is an upper bound), but has no *rational* number as supremum

(B) $\emptyset$  is bounded from above (e.g. $42$ is an upper bound), but has no *real* number as supremum (of course this example also works for (A))

(C) Least upper bound property means that every nonempty set that is bounded from above has a least upper bound (in the set). As the exmaple to (A) shows, $\mathbb Q$ does not have this property

(D) $\mathbb R$ is specifically constructed to have the least upper bound property!

Comment: If the exercise indeed says that one of the statements is true, I'd guess it's supposed to be B and they forgot about the "non-empty" part.

Answer (score 0):

Greatest lower bound for reals is $+\infty$, similarly, the supremum of reals is $-\infty$. I assume that whoever gave you that question meant that (B) should be correct(is there a non-empty assumption?), however, as $\emptyset$ is always a subset, and has $-\infty$ as upper bound (which is NOT real by the way), (B) is also false.